# Change the UITabBar Title on xCode / using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Have a UITabbar and 3 UITabItem in the storyboard. Have one of the tabitem   system item is been set to History.  Have the history system icon and system label history displayed.  Will I be able to change  text "History" to "Test"?

Comment: Do you need to change it programatically or can is it ok for you to change it throught the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the viewdidload()

```
let tabItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
let tabItem0 = tabItems[0] as UITabBarItem
let tabItem1 = tabItems[1] as UITabBarItem
let tabItem2 = tabItems[2] as UITabBarItem
tabItem0.title = "TitleThatYouWant-1"
tabItem1.title = "TitleThatYouWant-2"
tabItem2.title = "TitleThatYouWant-3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Tried this it's not working for history System item